# foo and _foo - about variables inside a class

Tags: python, class, variables

```
class ClassName(object):
    """
    """    
    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        """
        """
        self.foo = foo # read-write property
        self.bar = bar # simple attribute

    def _set_foo(self, value):
        self._foo = value

    def _get_foo(self):
        return self._foo

    foo = property(_get_foo, _set_foo)

a = ClassName(1,2)
#a._set_foo(3)
print a._get_foo()
```

When I print a._get_foo() the function _get_foo prints the variable self._foo .
But where does it come from? 
self._foo and self.foo are different, aren't they?

EDIT: The problem is that I still not understand what property does. Give me some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Docs for `property`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) explain how it's supposed to be used. There is no difference between these lines:

```
self.foo = foo # read-write property
```

and

```
a.foo = 3
```

You're also not supposed to call setters and getters manually.

**eta**: if you don't understand what `property` does after looking at the examples provided in the docs and reading our answers, you perhaps should just abstain from using it. It really is not the most essential of Python's features. You might want to start with a simpler example, which is easy to understand:

```
>>> class ClassName(object):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo


>>> a = ClassName(1, 2)
>>> a.foo
1
>>> a.foo = 42
>>> a.foo
42
```

Answer (score 2):

I really recommend this site:

http://adam.gomaa.us/blog/2008/aug/11/the-python-property-builtin/

A good explanation of the property-function.

Comment: +1 never heard of proprieties myself until now, and looks like this link explains it very nicely

Comment: The half of the programmers haven't heard of it.

Answer (score 1):

You define foo to be a property with getters and setters.

Those getters and setters use the variable `self._foo`, since you coded it that way:

```
def _set_foo(self, value):
  self._foo = value
```

In your case you would get a problem if you had a slightly different implementation:

```
class ClassName(object):
    """
    """    
    def __init__(self,):
        """
        """
        pass

    def _set_foo(self, value):
        self._foo = value

    def _get_foo(self):
        return self._foo

    foo = property(_get_foo, _set_foo)


 a = ClassName()
 print a.foo
 -> AttributeError

 b = ClassName()
 b.foo = 1 # implicitely sets self._foo !
 print b.foo
 >> OK, this is 1
```

As it happens you indeed should set `self.foo` in the `__init__` since the setter creates `self._foo`. (Or initialize `self._foo` in the `__init__` directly of course).

So, where do self.foo and self._foo come from? It's explicit in the code. self.foo is a property, and self._foo is the variable in which **you** decided to keep the value of that property.

Answer (score 1):

**`self._foo` and `self.foo` would be different except that you have assigned the property you created to the name `foo`: `foo = property(_get_foo, _set_foo)`.**

So now you have two names defined `foo` which is property that is defined in terms of the methods `_set_foo` and `_get_foo`. You also have a name `_foo` defined but this is the same attribute used in `_set_foo` and `_get_foo` and therefore in property `foo`.

**So you two names but only one object.**

```
        foo
        /\
       /  \
_set_foo  _get_foo
       \   /
        \ /
       _foo --> object
```

***Note:* For the example you have Python this is overkill, there is no need to use getter and setter methods unless they are going to have business logic in them.** Just use an attribute named `foo`, you can always wrap that in a property in future without affecting client code if it turns out that you need some smarts around the access of the attribute.

Change your code to:

```
class ClassName(object): 
    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
    self.foo = foo # read-write property
    self.bar = bar # simple attribute
```

Both `foo` and `bar` are read write, if you need finer control you can then consider using a property.

Comment: But why do I need a variable _foo? Isn't foo enough? Its hard to understand.

Comment: @kame foo alone is not enough if you need to use a property. However unless you have something more complicated to do do not use a property, just use an attribute named foo. In Python unlike in Java for example you can always change that to a property with the same name later without affecting any client code. So do not use any getter and setter methods unless they will have business logic in them.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, it "comes from" _set_foo. In your init, when you do self.foo = foo, that calls _set_foo(1), which performs self._foo = 1.

You can see this more clearly if you add a print statement inside _set_foo().

Comment: Why does self.foo = foo calls _set_foo(1) ?

Comment: @kame: you're setting value to the `foo`, that's why setter is called.